# php string to array output in foreach

Tags: php, string

My original data is `"aaa","bbb","ccc"`, how to converse string to array?

how to get the result like `aaa<hr />bbb<hr />ccc<hr />`? my code only return `"aaa","bbb","ccc"<hr />`.

```
$str = '"aaa","bbb","ccc"';
$ddd = array($str);
foreach($ddd as $aaa){
    echo $aaa.'<hr />';
}
```

Comment: `explode` - Race you to the manual.

Comment: Merely `explode` will not solve his problem. His string has quotes, as well as commas. Multiple explodes will though.

Comment: You are very correct, on a second thought `str_getcsv` could be handy here.

Comment: If your data **always** looks like this (i.e. double quotes) you could wrap it with `[]` and then parse it as JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
<?php
$str = '"aaa","bbb","ccc"';

$array = explode(',', $str);

foreach ($array as $element) {
    echo substr($element, 1, -1).'<hr />';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data looks like a well formatted CSV.

You can use [str_getcsv()](http://php.net/str_getcsv) to read the data directly to an array:

```
$str = '"aaa","bbb","ccc"';
$array = str_getcsv($str);

foreach ($array as $item) {
    echo $item . '<hr />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use str_replace to switch the commas with `<hr />` i have also removed the " for you too.

**for example**

```
$str = '"aaa","bbb","ccc"';
echo str_replace('"', '', str_replace(',','<hr />',$str));
```

Might not be the best way, but it will work :)